# F1 Real time Data feeds

Tags: xml, json, real-time, feed

I need to write an app that gets data input from real time Foruma One racing data feed.
The only feed I've come across till now is the official one so called "Live timing", the only problem is that there's no documentation for their protocol (which seems moreover to be a binary protocol), I tried contacting them but didn't hear from them yet.
I've found a .NET library that parses their feeds but it's based on a reverse engineered version of the real protocol which has a lot of bugs (and so crashes).

Now I'm stuck, and since I'm not a sport-expert I thought maybe there was any alternative I haven't found or heard of till now.

Any suggestion is gonna be helpful, please don't hesitate to share what you do know about this topic :)

Also, do you guys know of any other sport's related real time data feed that's accessible to developers ?

Comment: Can you post a link to the .net library by any chance?

Comment: Of course Stephen, here you go http://code.google.com/p/f1livetiming/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.